# I am using CloudFlare. How do I block access to my site admin to all but my IP address using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare, x-forwarded-for

My application runs on an ubuntu server which sits behind cloudflare. I want to redirect requests for `example.com/admin` to show 404 if the visitor is not coming from my IP `123.1.2.3`

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931765/allow-access-in-htaccess-based-on-the-httpx-forwarded-for)
I also tried using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-CONNECTING-IP} !^(123\.1\.2\.3)$
RewriteRule ^admin.php  - [R=404,L]
```

But none of them worked.
I have installed mod_cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.1.2.3
RewriteRule admin.php$ /404.php [R=302,L]
```

I've set it as `R=302` as that is a temporary redirect, I'm assuming you don't want this permanently, but if you do, change it to `R=301`.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Probably because I am using Cloudflare (proxy), which is why I tried x-forwarded-for, as per the link in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try: `RewriteCond %{CF-CONNECTING-IP} !123.1.2.3`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mod_cloudflare`, is it working? Does the PHP below display your actual IP address?

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

[mod_cloudflare instructions](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203656534-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Apache-2-4-) Assuming `mod_cloudflare` is working correctly, if you had an admin directory you should be able to do something like this.

**.htaccess** inside admin directory...

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 123.1.2.3
```

Or, if it's just a file that you need to protect, assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled, the following should work (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704961/allow-access-to-all-files-from-only-1-ip-address-and-redirect-all-others-to-othe)).

**.htaccess** in the root directory of your website...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.1.2.3
RewriteRule admin.php$ /404.php [R=301,L]
```

To enable `mod_rewrite` in ubuntu...

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-CONNECTING-IP} !=123.1.2.3
RewriteRule (.*) /404 [R]
```